# Обработчик в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, catel

Работаю с проектом на WPF, взаимодействие(связь) между View и ViewModel выполняется через catel. Каждому представлению xxxView.xaml отвечает модель xxxViewModel.cs, но так получается что есть однотипные представления в которых меняется только названия и величина параметров (разметка по шаблону).

Можно ли как то в один шаблон грузить по очереди (вызова окна) менять данные?(сейчас у нас 15 однотипных страниц с разными ключами на заголовки)

Comment: Я так понимаю, вы только учитесь писать в рамках MVVM? Если да, то я вам настоятельно не рекомендую на этом начальном этапе использовать какой-либо фреймворк типа этого вашего `catel`. Так как в вашем случае происходит подмена; вы не изучаете основополагающие принципы и общие способы реализации MVVM, а изучаете конкретную реализацию, то как это сделано в том или фреймворке. В итоге вы будете "плавать" и слабо понимать как и, что работает и почему это сделано так, а не иначе. `xxxViewModel.cs` - это файл не модели, а вьюмодели.

Comment: Вы правы, вьюмодель(как там и написано). В папке модели у меня осуществляется прием значений из базы и передача их во соответствующею вьюмодель. 
А Вы можете подсказать как это сделать в рамках MVVM ?

Comment: В рамках комментария, я могу лишь обрисовать в общих чертах. Создайте класс, допустим `MainViewModel`, в нем нужно создать свойства, для всех необходимых контролов из MainWindow, с помощью которых вы будете работать с данными из БД. Свяжите между собой вьюмодел и окно (для этого служит `DataContext`), затем сделайте привязку в контролах к свойствам у вьюмодел. Поищите в интернет готовую реализацию `RelayCommand`, скопируйте ее к себе в проект и используйте для реализации команд для кнопок. В конструкторе вьюмодел или же по команде загружайте данные из БД в классы модели и вперед.

Comment: Я как-то недавно писал простой [пример](https://yadi.sk/d/p1BzAvRL3EraxC) для демонстрации простого каркаса приложения. Там нет работы с БД и данными, но есть примеры работы с командами, с разными вьюмоделями и вьюшками. Загрузите и посмотрите, там все просто и сделано безовсяких фреймоворков.

Comment: Прошу прощения за возможно не ясный вопрос, но я спрашивал за "упрощение" (использования одной вью) приложения уже работает, хочу упростить его. На сколько я понимаю то что бы реализовать "шаблонный вью" нужно во вьюмодели сделать контроллер(или подключить контроллер) который будет подставлять все необходимые ключи(имена и значения той формы) сейчас по 15 файлов *View.xaml и *ViewModel.cs - а хочется использовать одну View и ViewModel + "контроллер.cs".  
п.с. посмотрел Ваш пример.

Comment: Да, не совсем понятно, что у вас есть. Если у вас 15 одинаковых вьюшек и к ним таких же вьюмоделей, то оставьте по одной и лишь меняйте данные во вьюмодели. Если из 15 нужно отображать в один момент только одну, то, да, нужнен класс для загрузки и отображения нужной вьюшки.